# Why does content keep being added to a file even after it was mv'd in bash?

Tags: bash, redirect, mv

Put this code in a script say `how.bsh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '1'
mv ./*  ../
echo '2'
```

inside a dir `a/b` and run it from `b` like this:

```
./how.bsh 1>list 2>&1
```

Finally `list` file ends up in dir `a` (as expected) **BUT** containing **'2'**!

How can this be;

***EDIT:***

Is that a fact?:

[image]

Comment: And there is a `list` file in the parent directory containing `1`?

Comment: Re: "How can this be?" -- why would you expect it _not_ to be?

Comment: @BenjaminW., `a` _is_ the parent directory, and that's where the file is correctly showing up. Nothing here is surprising, unusual, or unexpected..

Comment: Is that a fact? echo '2' happens after mv...

Comment: @GardroZeuth, yes, but the file was already opened before the `mv`. The file handle stays valid no matter if you rename the file; it's not attached to the name, it's attached to the inode. That's how UNIX filesystems have _always_ worked -- it's why you can upgrade programs while they're open on UNIX, for example.

Comment: ...really, the only filesystem used in modern days that doesn't have a concept of an inode is FAT -- even on Microsoft platforms, NTFS has inodes, it only pretends that it doesn't (and refuses to let files be renamed while they're open) for backwards-compatibility with software written for older versions of Windows. UNIXy systems have _never_ had that design flaw; inodes were described in the original 1978 paper by Richie and Thompson introducing UNIX.

Comment: BTW, this isn't just "in bash". You'd have the exact same behavior in C, in Python, in Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern filesystems have the concept of an *inode* -- a data structure tracking a file's contents, which exists independent of which directory entries link to that inode.

When you open a file, the file handle points to the inode -- the file itself -- not the directory entry. Thus, even when you rename the file, so long as the destination is on the same filesystem (so the `rename` syscall could be used), the file handle remains valid, and continued appends go to that existing file instance.